# Loop if data array

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I have trouble with my code. i want display record sum `jk = P` and `jk = L`

```js
const JK = ["L", "P"];
const data = [{
  "name": "Faris",
  "jk": "L"
}, {
  "name": "Nanda",
  "jk": "P"
}, {
  "name": "Ani",
  "jk": "P"
}]

var b = []
for (var a = 0; a < JK.length; a++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].jk == JK[a]) b.push(data[a] += 1)
  }
}

console.log(b);
```

I want `b = [1, 2]`

Comment: `b.push(data[a] += 1)` doesn’t really make sense. This code adds an arbitrary object to a number and overwrites the result (NaN) in `data` while pushing the result (NaN) to `b` as well. Counting is usually done with [objects](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), not with arrays.

Comment: A better way to post questions is to separate the code into language specific blocks and describe what you are trying to accomplish as well as what the problem is. Sometimes the community can suggest a better way of achieving your goal.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b.push(data[a] += 1)` doesn't work here. You need to set the array elements somewhere which is best done at the start, and then you can add to them. Try creating an array of 0s with the length of `JK`

```
var b = Array(JK.length).fill(0)
```

and then you can add to that array with your given index

```
if (data[i].jk == JK[a]) { b[a] += 1 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Notes**

OK, I think I understand what you are trying to do. You want to loop through a data list and count how many "jk" types exist.

**JS**

```js
const dataList = [
  { "name": "Faris", "jk": "L" }, 
  { "name": "Nanda", "jk": "P" }, 
  { "name": "Ani", "jk": "P" }
];

const counts = {};
const selectKey = 'jk';

// Loop through each item in dataList
for ( const item of dataList ){

  // Skip item if it is missing or missing the needed key
  if ( !item || !item[ selectKey ] ) continue;

  // initialize counts if first time accessing
  if ( !counts[ item[ selectKey ] ] ) counts[ item[ selectKey ] ] = 0;

  // increment key count
  counts[ item[ selectKey ] ]++;
}

console.log( 'counts object', counts ); // Result = {L: 1, P: 2}
console.log( 'counts array', [ counts.L, counts.P ] ); // Result = [ 1, 2 ]
```